# What is the maximum number of UNNotificationActions?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

What is the maximum number of UNNotificationActions a user can see and interact with when force pressing on a notification?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear:

> A notification can display up to four actions onscreen at once, and in
>   some cases may display only two of those actions.

From [Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationaction) Documentation

Comment: Interesting– I've actually shipped 5 before in an Apple approved app.